# Hi, I have problems with this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null". I trie to save some data from a form in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

here is the function, thank you very much for your help. I don't know what I'm failing at[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT1eP.png)

Comment: It looks like `hojaDestino` is null, that `sheet.getSheetbyName("BD")` isn't returning the value you expect it to return.

Comment: Your sheet name is incorrect. Similar questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cannot+read+property+getRange+of+null

Comment: Thank you very much, the sheet existed but it did not work. Rename the sheet and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no sheet exist  in the by name "BD". To be safe you can wrap it with if condition

```
hojadestino ? hojadestino.getRange(......) : null
```